# SQL Group by but additional column info is needed

Tags: sql, filter, group

I'm stuck with this query. I wonder if somebody can give me some idea how to resolve this.

Here is my table:

[image]

I basically want to group by product with the highest value of quality. But at the same time I also need to grab completed column.

```
select 
    Product, max(Quality) as Quality 
from 
    [Table]
group by 
    Product
```

When I group it, I cannot retrieve completed column.

[image]

Any other method to have same result above with completed column? in this case 1, 1 will be displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, try editing this question to follow those guidelines as it will help you solve your problem easier.

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Finally, you can read through [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the output of this query and inner join it with the original table...

```
select t1.*
from table_name t1
inner join 
    (select product, max(quality) as maxquality
     from table_name
     group by product) t2 on t1.product = t2.product 
                          and t1.quality = t2.maxquality
```

Comment: I tried inner join but similar problem as group by occured. Can you share me the query?

Comment: select t1.*
from table_name t1
inner join (select product, max(quality) as maxquality
   from table_name
   group by product) t2 on t1.product = t2.product and t1.quality=t2.maxquality

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can only `SELECT` columns that are part of the `GROUP BY` clause, or aggregate functions on any of the other columns.

You can either try adding it to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Product, 
       Completed,
       max(Quality) AS Quality,
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Product, Completed
```

Or use an aggregate function:

```
SELECT Product, 
       max(Completed),
       max(Quality) AS Quality,
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Product
```